# Python and Gstreamer

Tags: python, gstreamer

I'm creating a streaming application, using GStreamer with TCP pipeline, and i implemented start, pause, and stop.

but the problem is, that i can't seek, i tried to change the playback value from the server side, then i tried on the client side, and Finally tried to change the value on both at the same time, but in all cases it doesn't work. and I even tried to pause the playback then continue but nothing happens.

I'm having this problem with the seek and the volume. Any help please, I searched everywhere but i couldn't find anything that worked.

this is the code that i use for seeking

`self.pipeline.seek_simple(gst.FORMAT_TIME, gst.SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH, time)`

Comment: I would love answer your question but it really lacks a lot of information.  Show us a complete example that we could run.

Comment: Did you create your own src element from basesrc? Please supply some more information about your element and the pipeline.

Comment: it's `gst.FORMAT_TIME | gst.SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH` you have to *pipe* seek flags, not *chain* them.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could do the trick if you didn't find it yet:

> Seeking in Gstreamer is done with the seek() and seek_simple() methods. To be able to seek you will also need to tell Gstreamer what kind of seek it should do. In the following example we will use a gst.FORMAT_TIME format constant which will as you may guess do a time seek. :D We will also use the query_duration() and query_position() methods to get the file length and how long the file has currently played. Gstreamer uses nanoseconds by default so you have to adjust to that.

Here is an example: [Seeking with GStreamer](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/seeking.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to have the bus listening for seek events.  Try putting this in after setting up your pipeline:

```
self.bus = self.pipeline.get_bus()
self.bus.add_signal_watch()
```

If this doesn't work then please post more code.